# Error while creating foreign relation in knex - table creation race condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I'm new to knex and haven't touched RDBMS in years (been in NoSQL land), so bear with me here.

I've got two migration files, one for tracks and one for users (tracks are owned by users). Below are the relevant files:

### migrations/20190919103115_users.js

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('users', table => {
    table.increments('id');
    table.string('email', 50);
    table.string('first_name', 50);
    table.string('last_name', 50);
  }  
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('users');
};
```

### migrations/20190406112728_tracks.js

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('tracks', table => {
    table.increments('id');
    table.string('name', 140).notNullable();
    table.integer('owner_id').notNullable();
    table
      .foreign('owner_id')
      .references('id')
      .inTable('users')
      .onDelete('CASCADE');
    table.json('metadata');
  });
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('tracks');
};
```

When I run `yarn knex migrate:up`, I get:

```
migration file "20190406112728_tracks.js" failed
migration failed with error: alter table "tracks" add constraint "tracks_owner_id_foreign" foreign key ("owner_id") references "users" ("id") on delete CASCADE - relation "users" does not exist
```

I find the official Knex documentation to be pretty lacking (it's more of a reference than anything else) and can't figure out what I'm missing. Obviously I need some way for `users` to be created before `tracks`, but don't know how.

EDIT:

It seems this is how it's done: https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/938#issuecomment-131491877

But it seems wrong to just put the entire set of tables in a single migration file. I thought the point was to create one migration file per table?

Comment: It seems perfectly reasonable to me to have a single function so that you can control the order of creation/deletion to account for foreign keys. That's how I would do it in a SQL script. And all of the users in the article you linked seem to agree.

Comment: @JacobH True. It seems separate migration files are for later additions to the schema to add on columns/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migration files are **sorted by name** before execution, so looks like your `tracks` file name has an earlier date, therefore it runs before creation of users.

just run `npx knex migrate:make create_users`, and then `npx knex migrate:make create_tracks`.

it will generate new files with the proper timestamp, copy your code to the new files, delete the old ones :]